# Parse datatime from string value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have value in the database as below:

```
04/14
01-15
02/15
```

I need parse those value to data time format. Even if become 01/04/2014 from 04/14, it's ok.

I've tried like below which is not working.

```
var strDate = "04/14";
var format = "d";
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var result = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, format, provider);
```

Comment: I suggest you search SO for one of the dozens of questions concerning date parsing. I bet you find an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, your string and format doesn't match.

When you use `DateTime.ParseExact`, your string and format should match *exactly*. I strongly suspect your try to use ["d" standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) in your case which is wrong. This method take this format as a single digit of day which is not enough to parse your strings.

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes formats as a string array `MM-yy` or `MM/yy` with a culture that have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx).

```
DateTime dt;
var formats = new[] {"MM/yy", "MM-yy"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Since your string have only month and year parts, it's day part will be the first day of the month and time part will be midnight by default.